# Integrating and Plotting Polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I have a points for a given polynomial. I would like to integrate, preferably using a definite integral, but I believe in the syntax of using polyint this isn't possible without some manipulation. Regardless, if I can just get it to integrate I'll be able to take it from there.

```
 dpt=coeffvalues(fitresult{4});
 ppval=polyval(dpt,xx)

 cpdt=coeffvalues(fitresult{2});
 cpval=polyval(cpdt,xx)

 pint=(ppval./cpval);
 intp=polyint(pint);
```

I've tried doing this a couple of ways...One being fitting the results of the pint curve, finding the coefficients and then using the polyint function. But no matter which way I do it I always get the same three errors:

```
 Error using  ./ 
 Matrix dimensions must agree.

 Error in polyint (line 16) 
 pi = [p./(length(p):-1:1) k];

 Error in ptintegrate97 (line 61)
 intp=polyint(ptint);
```

Usually its the first error that is causing the problem, but when I do size(ppval) and size(cpval), they are both 837x1. So I'm kinda lost. I'm new to MATLAB sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

polyint won't work here, because it is expecting a series of polynomial coefficients, but you are providing a series of numbers that are the output of the previous calculation and have no relation to any polynomial coefficients whatsoever.  The error you are getting is because the shape of `pint` is wrong.  But even if it was right, you wouldn't get the answer you want.

You can choose to integrate `pint` numerically if you want.  Using a simpson's rule on the `pint` values could certainly get you to a correct answer if your step size between points is small enough.  Or, you could return to doing a symbolic polynomial division in order to get an absolute integral.  I am not sure what exactly you are after, or what your requirements are.